# R - How to use sex in linear regression

Tags: r, regression

I'm working on different models of regression and one of the variables considered is sex. I noticed that if I change its structure the lm results are different. My question is then, how should sex be used in regression: character, factor or numeric?
Could you please explain this issue?
Thank you.

````
example 1: sex as character (f/m)

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 76.07688    6.66248  11.419 3.00e-12 
sex(m)      17.28248    1.29894  13.305 7.09e-14 
age         -0.77965    0.24200  -3.222  0.00314 
weight      -0.50905    0.05656  -9.000 6.82e-10 

example 2: sex ar factor (f/m)

(Intercept)  93.35936    6.73548  13.861 2.53e-14 
sex(f)      -17.28248    1.29894 -13.305 7.09e-14 
age          -0.77965    0.24200  -3.222  0.00314  
weight       -0.50905    0.05656  -9.000 6.82e-10 

example 3: sex as numeric (m=1 / f=0)

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 76.07688    6.66248  11.419 3.00e-12 
sex         17.28248    1.29894  13.305 7.09e-14 
age         -0.77965    0.24200  -3.222  0.00314 
weight      -0.50905    0.05656  -9.000 6.82e-10 

```
````

Comment: Only as a factor.

Answer (score 2):

For binary variable like sex, it does not matter whether you code as 0/1 or as m/f. The most important thing is the level chosen as the reference. In case of 0/1, 0 is taken as reference. You see that example 1 is the same as example 3 because both $f$ ($f=0$ in ex3 and sex(m) is reported in ex1) is taken as reference. In example 2, R takes $m$ as the reference. As a result, R reports sex(f).

P/S: Choosing the reference, in general, does not affect your analysis. If you notice, you see that age and weight do not change.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was just wondering if factor/char/number could affect the results. I needed to clarify that condition to be sure for future works.